# Vue resource and Django Rest Framework. How to update UserProfile with User primary key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

models

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, verbose_name="Location")
    ...
```

DRF views

```
class UserProfileView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

DRF urls

```
  url(r'^user/$', UserProfileView.as_view()),
  url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', UserProfileView.as_view()),
```

My Vue resource:

```
 Vue.http.patch(`${BASE_URL}/user/`, profile)
```

But I got error like this:

```
 ValueError: Cannot assign "3": "UserProfile.user" must be a "User" instance
```

How can I post User instance from Vue? (I'm trying to update location field sending PATCH like {user: 3, locations: [1, 2, 3]}

Comment: You didn't paste the associated serializer.

Comment: @Linovia What do you mean? I even cant add new row to UserProfile model having user id because it wants User instance (not user id)

Comment: Where's `UserProfileSerializer` code ?